# Accessing argo workflow archive via http leads to permission denied error

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, argoproj

I'm trying to access the Argo workflow archive via the REST API. The [documentation](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/access-token/) states that I need to create a role and a token, so I that's what I did. A role with minimal permissions can be created like so:

```
kubectl create role jenkins --verb=list,update --resource=workflows.argoproj.io
```

And in fact this works, I can now access the argo server with a command like `curl http://localhost:2746/api/v1/workflows/argo -H "Authorization: $ARGO_TOKEN"`.
However it seems that more permissions are needed to access endpoints such as `/api/v1/archived-workflows`, because all I get there is this:

```
{
  "code": 7,
  "message": "permission denied"
}
```

Presumably I need to specify other verbs and/or resources in the `kubectl create role` command, but I don't know which ones, and I can't find the relevant documentation. Any hints?

Comment: I wonder if that role only grants you access if you limit your query to the `argo` namespace. Maybe try with `?listOptions.fieldSelector=metadata.namespace=argo`. Just trying to infer from the [archive server source](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/a50ddb206cd57a4667a3daa35e37bb9ed80f8cf0/server/workflowarchive/archived_workflow_server.go#L58).

Comment: What version are you using? I couldn't reproduce this in 2.12.8.

Comment: Hey @MichaelCrenshaw, Thanks for your response. Adding the `listOptions.fieldSelector` query parameter indeed makes the `permission denied` message go away, so thanks!
I'm using whatever version it is you get by following the tutorial, i. e. `kubectl apply -n argo -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/stable/manifests/quick-start-postgres.yaml`. Presumably that's the latest version.

Comment: Wow that's wild... I must have set up permissions in a way that allowed me to get from all namespaces without error. Anyway I'll drop an answer version of the comment. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the role/serviceaccount/rolebinding created according to the docs only grant permissions to list Workflows in the `argo` namespace (whether archived or not).

The namespace can be specified for the Archive like so:

```sh
curl http://localhost:2746/api/v1/archived-workflows?listOptions.fieldSelector=metadata.namespace=argo -H "Authorization: $ARGO_TOKEN"
```